# Ignored properly imported module

Tags: python

So I'm in a beginner Python course trying to learn my first language. I've managed to make it this far, but I'm struggling with this. I want to use a module to perform a function. However, it seems to be completely ignoring my module.

Any suggestions?

```
import asgn4_module as mod
"""
imports the module, and then prints intro
"""
print ("Assignment 4")
print ()

"""
prompts for names and age.
If they're blank, reprompts them.
"""

firstname = (input ("Please enter your first name."))
while mod.is_field_blank (firstname):
    print ("First Name must be entered.")
    firstname = (input ("Please enter your first name."))
    continue
lastname = (input ("Please enter your last name."))
while mod.is_field_blank (lastname):
    print ("Last name must be entered.")
    lastname = (input ("Please enter your last name."))
    continue
age =(input ("Please enter your age."))
while mod.is_field_blank (age):
    print ("Age must be entered.")
    age =(input ("Please enter your age."))
    continue
while mod.is_field_a_number (age):
    print ("Age entered must be a number.")
    age =(input ("Please enter your age."))
    continue
"""
inputs all received properly, print message calling those variables, then prints the end
"""
if int(age) >= 40:
    print ("Well, " + firstname + " " + lastname + "it looks like you're over the hill.")
else:
    print ("It looks like you have many programming years ahead of you, " + firstname + " " + lastname)
print ()
print ("End of assignment 4")
```

This is asgn4_module.py

```
"""
this module determines if the string is blank, or a number.
"""

def is_field_blank (string):
    string == ""

def is_field_a_number (string):
    string is int
```

Comment: You need to return a value from each function using `return` keyword

Comment: e.g. `return string == ""` will give you a `True` if the string is "", otherwise `False`. `string is int` won't work. I assume you want to check if the string can be *converted* to an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not checking empty but input string against `'g'` which I think is not the correct as you have explain your code. And you also have to return the case condition.

Update your module like this

```
"""
this module determines if the string is blank, or a number.
"""

def is_field_blank (string):
    return False if len(string) else True

# for python3
def is_field_a_number (string):
    return not string.isnumeric
```

for python2

```
# for python2
def is_field_a_number (string):
    return not isinstance(string, int)
```

Comment: Ah- Sorry! I used "g" in the compiler thingie to check the module was being imported properly.

Can you please explain what len(string) means?
and isinstance(string,int)?

I edited the OP to better reflect my code as it should be ("" instead of "g")

Comment: @LouiseTheZero `len` is python `in-built` method to check the `length`. so if user do not enter his name it will calculate length of blank string which is `0 (consider False by compiler in python)`. else True will be returned

Comment: @LouiseTheZero `isinstance` is also python `in-built` method to check the type (instance) of an object. so here `isinstance(string,int)` it will check if the input is type of integer or not. Also please note if you are using python3 then enter number will be in string, for this case I have update my answer

Comment: Hmmm. I copy/pasted the code you have there and it still didn't work.
I'm on python 3.74

Comment: @LouiseTheZero , have you tried with my new update. Also what the issue in running code?. Logic or module import issue?

Comment: `string.isnumeric` will return True if there are only numeric characters in string, False otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid it still doesn't work. I changed it to uh `return string == ""` and that works over `return len(string)`, so that's perfect, but having `return string.isnumeric` ALWAYS reprompts for reentering the age, specifying it must be numeric.

Comment: @LouiseTheZero, found the issue, actually you are checking the condition in `while loop` that until field is blank it should keep asking for the same.
So here we have to return the opposite result from called method. i.e if string is not blank it should return False so while loop get terminated. Please check update

Comment: Oooh. Is there a handy `string.isnotnumeric` type thing? or do I gotta rearrange the code in the main file?

Comment: @LouiseTheZero no there is no such handy string method. For all available method you can just type `help(str)` in you terminal it will give you clear explanation of all attribute of string object. If you type `help(str.isnumeric)` it will show the specific explanation for `isnumeric`. Hope it helps

Comment: @LouiseTheZero , You are welcome, I'm glad to help you.
 if it helps your doubt then please upvote/ accept it as answer. Thanks

Comment: Voted you up. I'm struggling with something else now if you can help me? I rewrote it to be a giant if statement. `if mod.is_field_a_number (age):` then it prints properly, else it goes to a while loop asking for numeric input. However, it always interprets the if statement as true, going right into printing properly.